# simcity nuclear meltdown even at level 4+ education

Tags: simcity-2013

My nuclear power plant just went in to meltdown, even though I have a high level education. What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I power everything nuclear, never had a meltdown. So, not really sure what causes that to happen.

Comment: let it be a mystery, i have switch to fusion power plant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first picture is the quick summary.  There are green hats for residential education coverage (looks good) and yellow gears for industrial technology coverage (looks like community college, do you have a university?).

Click the gears button in the quick summary to bring up the tech dataview.  This dataview lets you see the tech points in each building.

Tech points are generated when a student enters a community college or university.  The points then travel to an industrial building or nuclear plant.  Community college generates level 2 points, while university generates level 3 points.  A nuclear reactor has the ability to store BOTH kinds of points.

Things that may have gone wrong include:

- Not enough students to generate the required tech points.
- Not enough higher learning buildings for students to attend.
- Grade or High School buildings are taking students away from the higher learning buildings.
- Too much traffic so students couldn't get to the higher learning buildings.
- Too much industrial so the tech points didn't make it to the reactor.

If a MidTech or HighTech Industrial building runs out of tech points, it will soon abandon for "lack of skilled workers".

If a reactor runs out of tech points, well - you've seen that.

Also Note: since school is only open during the day, buildings have to last the night with their accumulated tech points.

Also also note: some specializations require tech points (electronics, computers)